# How to handle background tap in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in my app and I want to handle the background tap of it to do some cool stuff, but I tried several solutions and neither of them was too good.

Things I've tried:

- Adding a background view behind the `UICollectionViewCells` and handling the tap on that
- Adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UICollectionView`'s view (which is the same as it's `collectionView` property)

The problem in both cases is that while it handles the tap of the background perfectly, it also handles the tap when it's on a `UICollectionViewCell`, so when the user selects an item, but in that case it shouldn't because these 2 things have different actions in my app.

Comment: If your collectionView's cell has subView of UIImageView then you need to put `imageViewName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` because by default it is NO.

Comment: @iPatel No, it doesn't and btw, my problem is really the opposite of it, that both things handle the tap.

Comment: is in your case, selection (by single tap) of cell and selection (by single tap) of background is different ????

Comment: @iPatel Yes, the whole problem is that they aren't supposed to have the same effect.

Comment: I've tried 1st approach and it gives me different results for cell and background tap. Please, share your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I tried to set gesture recognizer to background view. I managed to get separate events.

```
self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
self.collectionView.backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];
self.collectionView.backgroundView.gestureRecognizers = @[tapRecognizer];
```

Comment: This on works for me too, thanks. The problem for me was `cancelsTouchesInView`

Comment: Small note: this also works with a simple view as the background view like `self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];`